# Return record with start IP and end IP as range that an IP address falls between?

Tags: sql, ip-address

I have approximately 5.5 million records that contain IP address information. The table has a low end and a high end for each record. Let's call this range `ip_start` and `ip_end`. This is mixed IPv4 and IPv6 addresses.

What I need to do is find the one, single record where any given IP address falls between the start and end ranges.

Even taking only IPv4 addresses into account, running the function found [here](https://www.periscopedata.com/blog/comparing-ip-addresses-in-sql.html) takes a full 58 seconds to run when you convert the passed in IP address and the start and end ranges. This is, quite obviously, unacceptable.

I could do this in C# but I honestly think SQL is going to be faster because I'm using entity framework and I'll be making network calls via WCF... the less times I throw across the wire, the better.

I thought about running a conversion using the function in the previously supplied link and having two indexed `bigint` columns but then... what in the world would I do with IPv6 addresses? Obviously I can't just convert those the same way because empty sections in the IPv6 address are actually empty while you have a weird "similar" of 0 in IPv4.

Does anyone have any suggestions or places to look?

And just for the sake of reference, the link mention gives us the following function:

```
create function dbo.IPAddressToInteger(@ip as varchar(15))
   returns bigint
as
begin
return (
  convert(bigint, parsename(@ip, 1)) +
  convert(bigint, parsename(@ip, 2)) * 256 +
  convert(bigint, parsename(@ip, 3)) * 65536 +
  convert(bigint, parsename(@ip, 4)) * 16777216
)
end
go
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a strategy rather than exact code.

First, update your table to have integer ips.  The code is not going to work with the string representation.  Here is one method:

```
alter table t add ipstart_int unsigned;
alter table t add ipend_int unsigned;

update t
    set ipstart_int = dbo.IPAddressToInteger(ipstart),
        ipend_int = dbo.IPAddressToInteger(ipend);
```

Then create an appropriate index on `ipstart_int, ipend_int`.

Then, run the query by doing something like:

```
select top 1 ip.*
from t ip
where ip.ipstart > dbo.IPAddressToInteger(@ip)
order by ipstart asc;
```

With a bit of luck, this will use the index and be very quick.  You can then compare the resulting end ip to be sure that `@ip` is, indeed, in the right range.

Comment: That's what I was thinking but before I dive into that, how's that going to handle IPv6 addresses (hint, it doesn't like those)? That's hex. I could convert to decimal and calc based on that and I'm pretty sure that just within IPv6 the numbers for each range will be unique. Aside from checking for colons to convert it first, can you think of a better strategy?

Comment: @MetalPhoenix . . . I would be inclined to store IPV4 and IPV6 in different tables.  The key lengths are quite different and the approach for optimization might also be differ.

Comment: whoa, I hadn't thought of that but it makes perfect sense and ....wow, thank you! I'll count this as an answer because it really addresses what I needed (and in ways I hadn't considered)

Comment: Yeah, copying the v4 addresses to it's own table and start/end pre-converted columns cut the query down to 7 seconds even without indexes. This might actually be what I'm looking for.

Answer (score 0):

Even by pre-converging the data and having an index, the query could be quite slow.

If you know that the ranges *do not overlay*, there is no need to have both a start and end.  Instead, use the index to find the start just before your IP, then scan forward for the next entry.  Details (in MySQL): http://mysql.rjweb.org/doc.php/ipranges  (That covers both IPv4 and IPv6.)